# Django - Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server on Production

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I was trying to deploy my Django project on [Render](https://render.com) . Everything works fine except for the media files. I can't figure out the issue here.

I have added the followings into my **settings.py**:

```
DEBUG=False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

MEDIA_URL = '/contents/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/contents/')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have created a Post (using models) before deploying. It had an image located a `./static/contents/Screenshot_334.png` After deploying this image is accessible at `https://someusername.onrender.com/static/contents/Screenshot_334.png` . But if I create a new post from the deployed site I get a **404 error**. The site doesn't cause any issue while its in the development mode.

**Here's a portion of LOGS from Render:**
[image]

`https://someusername.onrender.com/static/contents/Screenshot_334.png` (created while development) is accessible but `https://someusername.onrender.com/static/contents/Screenshot_1.png` (created post-production) is inaccessible. Also, static files (css, js) working fine.

I checked all the  files and directories using the following piece of code:

```
res = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for name in files:
        res.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

`Screenshot_334.png` and `Screenshot_1.png` both are in the same directory

I also tried switching `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to `'contents'`, `'contents/'`, `'static/contents/'` and all the possible variations.

**UPDATE:**
I have found a workaround since I couldn't figure it out myself. I have mapped `media` to the `urls.py` and used **FileResponse**

Here's how `views.py` looks:

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def media(request, path:None):
    img = open('./contents/'+path, 'rb')
    response = FileResponse(img)
    return response
```

I'm aware this might cause security issues but I think it won't do me any harm since it is a project just for learning.

Comment: Have you used nginx ?

Comment: No, not too familiar with nginx. Can you tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

Add `whitenoise` in your installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'whitenoise',
'accounts',
```

]

then add `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` in your middleware right after the first line.

try configring the static files as below in your `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

MEDIA_URL = 'contents/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/contents'
```

edit your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path(....)
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
   document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
   document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
)
```

Comment: did everything you mentioned, still getting a 404

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: try removing `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"`

Comment: yes I did run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: removing `STATICFILES_STORAGE` also didn't work :(